# Unity3D new input system run while walk is still being performed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, controller, 2d

I am working on a 2D game and I am using the new Unity3D InputSystem.

My walk works like it should.

Basically I get the input float that changes with A and D to go in the direction it should.
I am then sending the float with a command to the move script to move.

The problem I am having is , when I also hold the run button (Z) and I am still walking (pressing A - D) , I am still walking at that speed and doesn't change the speed untill I release the walk buttons.

If I hold the run button (Z) before walking , THEN it runs.
But I want to run while walking.

My current code:

```
private InputAction movementInput, runInput;
private bool isRunning;

private void Awake()
{
    movementInput.performed += context => OnMove(context);
    movementInput.canceled += context => OnMove(context);

    runInput.performed += context => this.isRunning = true;
    runInput.canceled += context => this.isRunning = false;
}

private void OnMove(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
{
    if(!isRunning)
    {
        movementComponent.move(mySpriteRenderer, context.ReadValue<float>());
        Debug.Log("NotRunning");
    }
    else
    {
        movementComponent.run(mySpriteRenderer, context.ReadValue<float>());
        Debug.Log("Running");
    }

}
```

So after holding the Z button to run while walking (pressing A or D) I don't receive the "Running" Debug.
If I stop and release the A and D buttons , hold the Z button and THEN press A or D , then I receive the "Running" Debug but if I release it while still holding the A or D it is still running.

It seems like it creates a snapshot of what the values were at the start of the move call and then ignore everything that has changed during that time.

Answer (score -1):

If I were you, I would have tried a different way to move the character:
Add to the player a characterController component and give the script a reference.

```
[SerializeField] private CharacterController chr;
[SerializeField] private float speed;

void Update(){
    float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    Vector3 dir = new Vector2(horizontal, 0);
    chr.Move(dir * speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Comment: That is using the old input system that will be deprecated. I knew how to do it with that , but I want to use the new Input System which is event based.